# Exporting java program with processing elements to executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, export, processing, executable

I have a java project with processing elements that compiles and runs fine inside of Eclipse, but I need to export it to an executable. When I do this via Eclipse's export wizard, it produces a jar, but that jar produces runtime errors when it's double clicked or called from the command line. First it was giving me this:

```
C:\Users\Rachel\School\MQP>java -jar Simworm14.jar
Catched MalformedURLException: Could not open InputStream for URL 'rsrc:gluegen-
rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar', while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class
 com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:rsrc:gluegen-rt.jar!/com/jogamp/
common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
): [ rsrc:gluegen-rt.jar -> rsrc: ] + gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar -> sl
im: jar:rsrc:gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar!/
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't loa
d library: C:\Users\Rachel\School\MQP\gluegen-rt.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1706)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoad
erBase.java:551)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.ja
va:64)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNIL
ibLoaderBase.java:96)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.j
ava:414)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrar
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:388)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:203)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:173)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
        at processing.opengl.PJOGL.initSurface(PJOGL.java:250)
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.initPrimary(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:62
44)
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:16
25)
        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

So I tried pasting gluegen-rt.dll into the given directory, and then it gave me this error instead:

```
C:\Users\Rachel\School\MQP>java -jar Simworm14.jar
Catched MalformedURLException: Could not open InputStream for URL 'rsrc:gluegen-
rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar', while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class
 com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:rsrc:gluegen-rt.jar!/com/jogamp/
common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
): [ rsrc:gluegen-rt.jar -> rsrc: ] + gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar -> sl
im: jar:rsrc:gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar!/
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\
Rachel\School\MQP\gluegen-rt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoad
erBase.java:551)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.ja
va:64)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNIL
ibLoaderBase.java:96)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.j
ava:414)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrar
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:388)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:203)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:173)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
        at processing.opengl.PJOGL.initSurface(PJOGL.java:250)
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.initPrimary(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:62
44)
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:16
25)
        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

After some googling, it appears this dependency issue might be a bug with jogl: https://java.net/jira/browse/JOGL-346 but I find it hard to believe that nobody has been able to export any processing applications from Eclipse. There's got to be a way, hasn't there?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Processing requires native libraries, which it doesn't look like you're including. You need to at least put the JOGL jar for the system you're on, but that won't help you deploy to other systems.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tool that helps you create self-extracting runnable jar files that handle Processing's native libraries automatically so it works on every system: http://StaticVoidGames.com/SvgExe/